# Get Certificate Intended Purposes

Tags: powershell, ssl

I have this code that gets informations about "Local Machine" SSL certificates and stores them in a CSV file. My concern is that I did not find a proper name defining these certificates. So I'm asking whether there is a field that indicates a certificate name?

Also, I want to store the SSL certificates' "Intended Purposes" and I could not figure out how to do it.

Final Question, I found that there are some certificates where the field "Intended Purposes" has an `ALL` value, so I want to know what are the purposes mentioned in this case?

This is my script that I want it to show me also the "Intented Purposes" and if found the name of the certificate.

```cs
$StartDate = Get-Date
$CertPath = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\'
$CertsDetail = Get-ChildItem -Path $CertPath -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.PsIsContainer -ne $true
} | ForEach-Object {
    $DaysLeft = (New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End $_.NotAfter).Days
    if ($DaysLeft -lt 1) {
        $Under30 = $true
        $Expired = $true
        $Text = "The Certificate is expired"
    } elseif ($DaysLeft -lt 30) {
        $Under30 = $true
        $Expired = $false
        $Text = "The Certificate is but valid about to expire"
    } else {
        $Under30 = $false
        $Expired = $false
        $Text = "The Certificate is still valid and not going soon to expire"
    }
    $FinalDate = Get-Date $_.NotAfter -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Text = $Text
        Subject = $_.Subject
        ExpireDate = $FinalDate
        DaysRemaining = $DaysLeft
        Under30Days = $Under30
        Expired = $Expired
    }
}
$CertsDetail | Where-Object {
    $_.DaysRemaining -lt 3650
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\SECnology\Data\Utilities\Certificate_State.csv'
```

Comment: See [this article](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/how-to-retrieve-certificate-purposes-property-with-cryptoapi-and-powershell.aspx) on how to expand the Extensions which contain the purposes.

Comment: I tried the code but it shows me nothing neither a result neither an error

Answer (score 1):

Following script iterates Cert Extensions and and if a Usage, stores in variable $Usage which is incorporated into the [PSCustomObject]

**Edit: Incorporated [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz)s valuable hints**

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\22\SO_56254011.ps1
$StartDate = Get-Date
$CertPath  = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\'
$FileOut   = 'C:\SECnology\Data\Utilities\Certificate_State.csv'
$CertsDetail = Get-ChildItem -Path $CertPath -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.PsIsContainer -ne $true
} | ForEach-Object {
    $DaysLeft = (New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End $_.NotAfter).Days
    if ($DaysLeft -lt 1) {
        $Under30 = $true
        $Expired = $true
        $Text = "The Certificate is expired"
    } elseif ($DaysLeft -lt 30) {
        $Under30 = $true
        $Expired = $false
        $Text = "The Certificate is but valid about to expire"
    } else {
        $Under30 = $false
        $Expired = $false
        $Text = "The Certificate is still valid and not going soon to expire"
    }
    $FinalDate = Get-Date $_.NotAfter -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'
    $Usages = foreach($key in $_.Extensions){
      if('KeyUsages' -in $key.psobject.Properties.Name ){ $key.KeyUsages}
      if('EnhancedKeyUsages' -in $key.psobject.Properties.Name){
          $key.EnhancedKeyUsages.FriendlyName
      }
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Text         = $Text
        Subject       = $_.Subject
        ExpireDate    = $FinalDate
        DaysRemaining = $DaysLeft
        Under30Days   = $Under30
        Expired       = $Expired
        Usages        = $Usages-join ';'
    }
}
$CertsDetail | Out-Gridview
$CertsDetail | Where-Object {
    $_.DaysRemaining -lt 3650
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $FileOut
```

Sample output.

```
Text          : The Certificate is expired
Subject       : CN=SITHS CA v3, O=Carelink, C=SE
ExpireDate    : 28-11-2015 07:02
DaysRemaining : -1271
Under30Days   : True
Expired       : True
Usages        : CrlSign, KeyCertSign
```

Comment: Thank you it worked but I have found some empty fields and others that contains System.Object[] in my csv file

Comment: If you compare the certs with `certlm.msc` does output differ?

Comment: I corrected `System.Object []` using `| Out-String) .Trim () `towards the end of the $ Usages line but for the empty fields I compared with certlm.msc and they are the same results (some empty fields)

Comment: **1.** `if ( 'KeyUsages' -in $key.psobject.Properties.Name ) { $key.KeyUsages}` and `if ( 'EnhancedKeyUsages' -in $key.psobject.Properties.Name ) { $key.EnhancedKeyUsages.FriendlyName}` and **2.**  `Usages = $Usages -join ';'` when defining the resulting `PSCustomObject`.